# Update delay for dataflow UDF

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I have a dataflow from pub/sub to bigquery that uses a javascript UDF to manipulate data. If I modify the file in cloud storage, does the running dataflow automatically update to start using this new UDF, is there a delay or do I have to trigger it manually? I changed the UDF but the dataflow behaves as if it were running with the old one.

Also, what is the best way to debug these UDF that run on dataflow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You mean the Dataflow Template, right?

Unfortunately, the UDF does not refresh when you change the file. To update with a new file, you need to perform a Pipeline update, or stop / restart your pipeline.

As for debugging the UDFs, I am not sure what's the best way; but you can access the pipeline code in [the DataflowTemplates repository in Github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/), and debug the pipeline by running locally, or writing a reduced version of it.